# How do I insert new cells in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to add a row to a tableview using

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

It throws an exception where I call insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:, which says

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

It is returning the correct number of rows and sections, but it never makes it to cellForRowAtIndexPath before throwing the exception.  I am doing this with a storyboard also and I have the tableView set to have static cells because the majority of the tableView does in fact have static cells.  I really don't want to switch over to dynamic prototypes because then I can't have IBOutlets and IBActions, which I am using, and I would have to essentially start over with respect to the layout of the cells.  Is there any way for me to get rid of this exception without changing my tableView to have dynamic prototype cells?

***Edit***

The line right before what I posted is

```
[itemsInCurrentPurchase insertObject:itemName atIndex:0];
```

which is supposed to update the array.  I am using

```
[itemsInCurrentPurchase count]
```

for my number of rows in section and it is returning the correct number after the update.  The problem is that the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not even being reached.  During the update is there anything else that gets called between the number of rows and the cell type that could be causing this error?

Comment: Did you update the datasource array before insertion? You need to update it before calling this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to update your data source with this new object before inserting the row. Otherwise it will crash while trying to update the table view with this new row.

for eg:-

```
[self.dataSourceArray insertObject:object atIndex:indexPath.row];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: Can you explain what `@[indexPath]` does? Does it create an array with  `indexPath` as its only object?

Comment: @JackHumphries, Yes. For more details check this, http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: I did this, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What if you just comment out `insert` method and add `[tableview reloadData]` is it still crashing? Also is this section already there? Are there any other rows in this section? If not, you have to use `insertSections` method.

Comment: Yes, it is, I tried this earlier and just assumed that they did about the same thing because I get the same error.

Comment: In that case the error is somewhere else. You are trying to access an object which is not there in the array somewhere. Try adding exception break point and check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: I have used break points and it shows that the insertRowsAtIndexPaths is where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @user1654889, Remove that line and add `[tableview reloadData]` and then check using break points. Is it still showing that crash?

Comment: The breakpoint still shows up on the    [tableview reloadData].

Comment: In that case try `[itemsInCurrentPurchase addObject:itemName]` and then reloadData and check what is the new error?

Comment: I figured it out.  It had to do with how I was trying to reuse static cells in my table.  Thanks for your help though.